How to create dynamic chart in Excel?
I'm creating a dashboard using EXCEL, and I have a graph that I present revenue by month year
(I present the growth in percentages) and I want to ass a button to switch this data range dashboard to present revenue in numbers also.
My data range is like this -

and my graph is look like this -

I want to add a button that will have the possibility to change from % to the numbers of revenue. I there any option?

Here's an attempt using a slicer:
Method
For buttons, use a slicer with display options, and change the display labels based on selection.
Steps
I think you have already entered your data as table; otherwise create table with your data, as the formula used uses structured references.

Add another sheet for the helper table with options

Column with title "Show" with values "Percent" and "Value"

Select these cells and add a table named "dataLabel"

Add a column with title "Selected" with formula
=AGGREGATE(3,5,[@Show])
this will have the value 1 for the visible rows.

With the table selected add a slicer and select the "Show" field.

Cut this slicer and paste into the sheet with the chart.

To get the value of the selection and use it in our formula, enter the following in K8: =FILTER(dataLabel[Show],dataLabel[Selected]=1). Please a create name for this later as it will be easier to use.



To show percent/value based label, ddd another column to your table, for example "Selected label 2023" and "Selected label 2024"

Here we will change the display label based on the selections (for example 2023 and 2024):
=IF($L$8 = "Percent","",TEXT([@2023], "#,##0"))

=IF($L$8 = "Percent",
TEXT(IF([@2024]<[@2023],[@[Data Label -]],[@[Data Label +]]), "0%"),
TEXT([@2024], "#,##0"))


TEXT is used format the values based on selection.

Please adjust the logic if it is not correct



For each data series (2023, 2024 etc.), select the data label and choose "Format Data Labels…"

If checked, uncheck "Value" and select "Value From Cells…"
Enter the range - in this example it is =Sheet2!$I$2:$I$13




Result



Hi, I would happy if you could explain me what is the formula you add for with the IF? the first one.. I don't understand.. please note that after this formula, the values are not the second value is not the same, so maybe the formula doesn't correct?

Could you please try the update? Please let me know if any of the steps needs more explanation.

Hi, thanks. But I need that the values of 2024 and 2025 will appear on the graph, not the diff. Second, what is the aggregate function? I don't know this. where to write this? I don't really understand from there...

AGGREGATE function - Microsoft Support Updated to show data values instead of diff. Hope you can adopt this example to a solution you need.
